# Calculate Percentage from multiple column value

Tags: mysql

I want to find MySql query for calculate percentage of the job done based on values on different column, previously i did this in Microsoft Excel using countif, but now i want to create same table on mysql.

this is my current table

```
Parts Already Build : 
------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | Front   |  Rear   |  Left   | Right   |  Up     |  Down   |
__________________________________________________________________

| 01 | Done    |  Done   | Done    | Done    | Done    |  Done   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02 | Done    |  Done   | Done    | Done    | No Need | No Need |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 03 | Done    | Ongoing | Ongoing | Done    | Done    | Not Yet | 
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 04 | Not Yet | Not Yet | Not Yet | Not Yet | Not Yet | Not Yet |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

expected result

```
Parts Already Build : 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | Front   |  Rear   |  Left   | Right   |  Up     |  Down   |   %   |  Status  |
________________________________________________________________________________

| 01 | Done    |  Done   | Done    | Done    | Done    |  Done   |  100  | Complete |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 02 | Done    |  Done   | Done    | Done    | No Need | No Need |  100  | Complete |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 03 | Done    | Ongoing | Ongoing | Done    | Done    | Not Yet |   50  | Ongoing  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 04 | Not Yet | Not Yet | Not Yet | Not Yet | Not Yet | Not Yet |    0  | Not Yet  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note:

1. If all process is done or there is 6 "done" value in that 6 column then % column = 100
2. If the value is "No Need", it will be count as "Done".
3. if not all process is done/no process is done, then the table will only count how many "done" or "no need" value and convert it to percentage in % column (3/6 process is "done" = 50%)
4. if % is =100% then "Status" column = Complete / if =0% = Not Yet / if Else (1%-99% = ongoing)

Current Query :

```
SELECT
front,
rear,
left,
right,
up,
down,
_________________ AS %,
_________________ AS Status
FROM process
```

Comment: Is there some form of `id` value on each row?

Comment: yes there is, id as primary key and set to auto increment, but i didnt include that on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your given table structure, you need to add up all the cases where the status is `Done` or `No Need` to get a value for completeness, and this can then be used to generate the `%` and `status` columns:

```
SELECT `Front`, `Rear`, `Left`, `Right`, `Up`, `Down`,
        complete * 100 / 6 AS percent,
        CASE complete WHEN 6 THEN 'Complete'
                      WHEN 0 THEN 'Not Yet'
                      ELSE 'Ongoing'
        END AS status
FROM (SELECT *,
             0 + (Front = 'Done' OR Front = 'No Need')
               + (Rear  = 'Done' OR Rear = 'No Need')
               + (`Left`  = 'Done' OR `Left` = 'No Need')
               + (`Right` = 'Done' OR `Right` = 'No Need')
               + (Up    = 'Done' OR Up = 'No Need')
               + (Down  = 'Done' OR Down = 'No Need') AS complete
      FROM process) p
```

Output

```
Front       Rear        Left        Right       Up          Down        percent     status
Done        Done        Done        Done        Done        Done        100     Complete
Done        Done        Done        Done        No Need     No Need     100     Complete
Done        Ongoing     Ongoing     Done        Done        Not Yet     50      Ongoing
Not Yet     Not Yet     Not Yet     Not Yet     Not Yet     Not Yet     0       Not Yet
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9TDiZjAE2tScFgTnUduCps/0)

Comment: now, i want to select 1 column named (test_column) from another table named (test_table) from the database, what is the query to do this? where should i put it?

Comment: @Gnometa That becomes a different problem because you'll need a join. I think you should ask another question. Refer back to this one if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you should fix your data model first.  Instead of having six different columns for the directions, you should have just *two* columns, one for the direction, and another for the value.  Consider this version of your data:

```
id | direction | status
1  | Front     | Done
1  | Rear      | Done
1  | Left      | Done
1  | Right     | Done
1  | Up        | Done
1  | Down      | Done
2  | Front     | Done
2  | Rear      | Done
2  | Left      | Done
2  | Right     | Done
2  | Up        | No Need
2  | Down      | No Need
...
```

With this *normalized* version your data, we can write the following query fairly easily:

```
SELECT
    id,
    100.0 * AVG(status IN ('Done', 'No Need')) AS pct,
    CASE WHEN SUM(status NOT IN ('Done', 'No Need')) = 0 THEN 'Complete'
         WHEN SUM(status = 'Ongoing') > 0 THEN 'Ongoing'
         WHEN SUM(status = 'Not Yet') = COUNT(*) THEN 'Not Yet'
         ELSE 'Unknown' END AS status
FROM yourNewTable
GROUP BY
    id;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
SELECT front, rear, left_col, right_col, up, down,
FLOOR((IF(front = 'Done' OR front = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(rear= 'Done' OR rear = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(left_col = 'Done' OR left_col = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(right_col = 'Done' OR right_col = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(up = 'Done' OR up = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(down = 'Done' OR down = 'No Need', 1, 0))/6 * 100) AS Percent,
CASE WHEN FLOOR((IF(front = 'Done' OR front = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(rear= 'Done' OR rear = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(left_col = 'Done' OR left_col = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(right_col = 'Done' OR right_col = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(up = 'Done' OR up = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(down = 'Done' OR down = 'No Need', 1, 0))/6 * 100) = 100 THEN 'Complete'
     WHEN FLOOR((IF(front = 'Done' OR front = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(rear= 'Done' OR rear = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(left_col = 'Done' OR left_col = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(right_col = 'Done' OR right_col = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(up = 'Done' OR up = 'No Need', 1, 0) + IF(down = 'Done' OR down = 'No Need', 1, 0))/6 * 100) = 0 THEN 'Not Yet'
     ELSE 'Ongoing' END AS Status
     FROM Test
```

This is [demo](https://paiza.io/projects/yC0exjZU-ubvoigLbNuW2Q?language=mysql)

[image]

Comment: I added the demo link